# oAuth Authorization Server and Client (for another authorization service) in same Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am trying to create a service that is firstly responsible for acting as an OAuth client only to authenticate the user. It authenticates with an external authorization server i.e google login to authenticate the client.
Once the user is authenticated, this service will act as an authorization server to provide specific roles and authorities and within the new JWT token.
Like this:

[image]

Can I configure one Spring Boot app `my authorization service` to serve as both authorization server and client for another authorization server?
Would be nice if someone can provide some working example Spring Boot project.
Thanks a lot.